# Azure Container Service using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-management-api, azure-container-service

I would like to create azure container with resource group and cluster of specific Orchestrator Kubernetes cluster.

I know by using CLI its possible but I want to do this using Azure Rest API's for Container service from link given here

learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-service/containerservices/createorupdate

Registered my app in AAD and gave required permissions.

Got access token and making request to below api as per link

PUT management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/containerServices/{containerServiceName}?api-version=2017-01-31
but I am getting error as

```
{
"error":  {
"code": "InvalidResource"
"message": "The resource definition is invalid."
}
}
```

I understand we get this error when there is nothing in request body.

So my real question here is if I want to create container service with resource group and cluster using API request.

Request Body

```
    {
  "id": "myCluster",
  "name": "myCluster",
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/containerServices",
  "location": "southindia",
  "tags": {
    "tag": "test"
  },
  "properties": {
     "orchestratorProfile": {
      "orchestratorType": "Kubernetes"
    },
    "servicePrincipalProfile": {
      "clientId": "<clientid>,
      "secret": "<secret>"
    },
    "masterProfile": {
      "count": 1,
      "dnsPrefix": "testabc"
    },
    "agentPoolProfiles": {
      "name": "agentPool1234",
      "count": 2,
      "vmSize": "Standard_A1",
      "dnsPrefix": "testabcagents"
    },
    "linuxProfile": {
      "adminUsername": "kubeadmin",
      "ssh": {
        "publicKeys": [
          {
            "keyData": "sshkey"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response getting

```
{
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "An error has occurred in subscription <subscriptionid>, resourceGroup: tobeDeletedResourceGroup request: OrchestratorType has unknown orchestrator: ."
    }
```

Please help me out on this

Comment: your put body is invalid

Comment: @4c74356b41 I am getting same error for any orchestrator like Swarm, DCOS, or Custom

Comment: @4c74356b41 what wrong things you see in PUT body. will you please elaborate bit please? or if you have sample PUT body please provide me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are missing from Azure REST API documentation.
1) It requires version of orchestratorRelease with orchestratorType like this.  **"orchestratorProfile": {
      "orchestratorType": "Kubernetes",
      "orchestratorRelease": "1.7"
    }**
2) Next error i got about missing vmSize in Properties.MasterProfile.VMSize.
So I have added following updates to json

**"masterProfile": {
      "count": 1,
      "dnsPrefix": "testabc",
       "vmSize": "Standard_D2_v2"
    }**

Its very surprising and annoying that documentation is missing these 2 important json parameters.

Answer (score 0):

agentPoolProfiles should be an array of json objects. I pulled this example from [azure-cli's mock unit tests](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/2a59cee5b632bc714d439531b08f038cf7b1cf9e/src/command_modules/azure-cli-acs/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/tests/recordings/latest/test_acs_create_default_service.yaml#L356-L371) to help give you a frame of reference.

https://gist.github.com/bacongobbler/470b8d139536144edf91174916ec4036

Comment: Yes I updated my agentpools with "agentPoolProfiles": [{ "name": "agentPool1234", "count": 2, "vmSize": "Standard_A1", "dnsPrefix": "testabcagents"
    }], But Still getting the same error.